# Calculating cumulative distance in hive from a series of lat, lon points

Tags: hive

Given a table like this:

```
latitude longitude
```

we want to add a 3rd column to this table which would store the running distance

```
latitude longitude odometer
```

where the odometer for i-th row is computed as follows:

```
odometer_i = odometer_{i-1} + distance(lat_i, lon_i, lat_{i-1}, lon_{i-1})

distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) = sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2))

odometer_0 = 0 (first row)
```

how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key to solving this problem is to use windowing functions of hive - lag and sum.

Step 1: The first step is to enumerate the previous lat, long besides the current lat, long. This is done using the lag function and is the key to solving this problem:

```
SELECT *,
                    lag(latitude, 1) over (order by timestamp) as previous_latitude,
                    lag(longitude, 1) over (order by timestamp) as previous_longitude
                    from table
```

where we assumed existence of a `timestamp` column to order lat, longs in temporal order.

Step 2: The next step is to convert degrees into radians

```
                select *,
                radians(previous_latitude) as lat1,
                radians(previous_longitude) as lon1,
                radians(latitude) as lat2,
                radians(longitude) as lon2
                from step1
```

Step 3: Next we compute the distance between `(lat1, lon1)` and `(lat2, lon2)` using first order approximation of the haversine formula:

```
 select *, 
                    6378137.0 * sqrt(pow(lat1 - lat2, 2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * pow(lon1 - lon2, 2)) as distance
                from step2
```

Step 4: finally we calculate the running sum of the `distance` column:

```
select *, sum(distance) over (order by timestamp) as odometer from step3
```